# Change values in dictionary except for one key

Tags: python, dictionary, key

It's almost an hour that I am trying to solve this little problem.

> `Python` is an MIT student who loves fruits. He carries different types
>   of fruits (represented by capital letters) daily from his house to the
>   MIT campus to eat on the way. But the way he eats fruits is unique.
>   After each fruit he eats (except the last one which he eats just on
>   reaching the campus), he takes a 30 second break in which he buys 1
>   fruit of each type other than the one he just had. `Cobra`, his close
>   friend, one day decided to keep a check on `Python`. He followed him on
>   his way to MIT campus and noted down the type of fruit he ate in the
>   form of a string pattern (e.g. `AABBBBCA`). Can you help `Cobra`
>   determine the maximum quantity out of the different types of fruits
>   that is present with `Python` when he has reached the campus?
>
> Write a function `nfruits` that takes two arguments:
>
> - A non-empty dictionary containing type of fruit and its quantity    initially with `Python` when he leaves home (length < 10)
> - A string pattern of the fruits eaten by `Python` on his journey as observed by    `Cobra`.
>
> This function should return the maximum quantity out of the different
>   types of fruits that is available with `Python` when he has reached the
>   campus.
>
> For example, if the initial quantities are `{'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3}`
>   and the string pattern is `AC` then:
>
> 1. `A` is consumed, updated values are `{'A': 0, 'B': 2, 'C': 3}`
> 2. `Python` buys `B` and `C`, updated values are `{'A': 0, 'B': 3, 'C': 4}`
> 3. ´C´ is consumed, updated values are `{'A': 0, 'B': 3, 'C': 3}`
>
> Now `Python` has reached the campus. So the function will return 3 that
>   is maximum of the quantities of the three fruits.

It's an optional exercise for a MOOC and therefore it is not graded: I solved harder problem (much harder) but I am not able to solve it.

My attempt:

```
def nfruits(dictionary, string):
    i = 0
    string = sorted(string)

    for char in string:
        dictionary[char] -= 1
        # print dictionary
        i += 1
        for char in string[i:]:
            dictionary[char] += 1
            # print dictionary

     return dictionary[max(dictionary, key = dictionary.get)]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about adding `1` everywhere and then subtracting `2` for the specific key?

Something like

```
def nfruits(dictionary, string):
    i = 0
    string = sorted(string)

    for idx, char in enumerate(string):
        # We should update other fruits on all steps except the
        # last one
        if idx < len(string) - 1:
            for key in dictionary:
                dictionary[key] += 1
            dictionary[char] -= 2
        else:
            # for the last step - only decrement the fruit
            # Python ate
            dictionary[char] -= 1
        print dictionary
    return dictionary[max(dictionary, key = dictionary.get)]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    dd = {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3}
    print nfruits(dd, 'AC')
```

Update: one more option is just skip the `char` when we go over the dict:

```
def nfruits2(dictionary, string):
    i = 0
    string = sorted(string)

    for idx, char in enumerate(string):
        # Update the fruit Python ate
        dictionary[char] -= 1
        # update others he bought, skip this on the last step
        if idx < len(string) - 1:
            for key in dictionary:
                if key != char:
                    dictionary[key] += 1
        print dictionary
    return dictionary[max(dictionary, key = dictionary.get)]
```

Comment: It does not seem to work. For some entries yes but not for all of them!

Comment: it works but you need to make sure you don't reduce the count of any fruit < 0: with d = {'a' : 1, 'b' : 2, 'c' : 3} and string = 'aabbbbca' is impossible

Comment: @LorenzoFabbri what entries it doesn't work for? I updated the answer, there is a special case - on the last step we don't buy other fruits.

Comment: @gkusner you right, but I assume that inputs will represent only possible situations. Because in context of two friends an impossible situation means that Cobra was wrong in his recordings, so there is no wonder that we would get an incorrect final result.

Comment: Now it works perfectly. Thank you very much, now I have to understand it!

Comment: @LorenzoFabbri I added one more variant which is more straightforward - first decrement the one Python ate and then update others except this one.